# how to show only list of video links and play using Youtube Searching API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I learned the code of searching and showing results of youtube videos

but problem is that when I search again (typing another keyword), the results added under the previous results. I want to show only new results.

How to edit my code??

```
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // prepare the request
      var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 3,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      }); 
      // execute the request
      request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
           $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("item.html", function(data) {
                $("#youtube_results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
            });
           });      
       });
     });        
});

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("my_api_key");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
        // yt api is ready
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) your results list before appending the results:

```
//...
$("#youtube_results").empty();
$.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
  $.get("item.html", function(data) {
      $("#youtube_results").append(
        tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
  });
});
//...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there is problem that when I use empty() like that the results show only one content...although my maxResults is 3.
[test_page](https://dbtest-parkhk1757-1.c9.io/jadu/youtube) < -this is my test page

Comment: @HyungKyuPark - sorry, I didn't notice there's an `$.each()` in there, try now. By the way, that code looks really wrong - why are you "getting" the "item.html" file each time?

Comment: item.html contains <iframe> tag and it makes a shape of video content.
Actually, I followed step of this lecture (08:00 part)[lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vH2eZAM30s) Is it not that neccesary?

Comment: If you request the same resource (URL...) over and over again, you're getting the same result. It's pointless to do that more then once.

Comment: Thank you :) but how to fix it? Is it correct if I just remove "get" function and item.html?

Comment: Do it only 1 time (the `init` function could be a good place), and save the result (`data`) in a variable. Use that inside your `.each()`.

Comment: Oh sorry It is hard to understand for me. because I'm new to javascript and Object-Oriented Programming. So If you show me code I'll remember and study about the principle...Could you help me one more?

Comment: That's a bit too long for this format, but as a temporary solution (Not the best, but definitely better then what you now have), replace the order of calls - put `$.each` inside `$.get`. ONLY switch these 2 lines, nothing else.